# How to properly make a thousand requests to an API in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, api, sleep, array-splice

I have to make a thousand requests to the IGDB API and I am having troubles making this work. Everytime I run my script, it's loading for some time then my web host tells me "Error: there is a problem...It seems that something went wrong." (not very helpful I know).

Since I believe the issue comes from the amount of requests, I have tried reducing it but I am down to 60 requests with a pause of 4 seconds between each and still no success.

My latest try:

```
$splice = array_splice($array, 0, 60); 

foreach($splice as $key => $value){

    $request = wp_remote_get('https://igdbcom-internet-game-database-v1.p.mashape.com/games/?fields=*&search='.$value['Name'],
                array( 'headers' => array( 
                             'Accept' => 'application/json',
                             'X-Mashape-Key' => 'Key' )));

    $body = wp_remote_retrieve_body($request);

    $data_api = json_decode($body, true);

    sleep(4);

}
```

Would anyone know what I am doing wrong? I am running out of ideas...

Comment: You're probably doing nothing wrong.. except, you're falling into request timeout.

In general - web server (Apache, Nginx etc) has a set time it waits for any response from the script before it shows 'error' page. Additionally, PHP itself has time limit.

From PHP side you can set `set_time_limit(0)` to disable it. From web server side - you may not be able to change it, depending on your provider.

Generally you should make this a console command instead of a web page.

Comment: Why are you trying to perform a bulk import from a web page inside a CMS????!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

That's very likely to be nothing more than the timeout response from either PHP or the server.
Although there ways to go around these securities, they aren't for nothing.

You should use CLI to execute cargo queries, not CGI. CGI access is for regular users, whatever their role/priviledges. As a developer, you have access to the code, and to the server (or at least your sysadmin does if you are in a team). You SHOULD use command line to do these queries. It will take less time, will have less chance to fail and you'll have the error logs printed right away unless you redirect them to a file.

Comment: Sorry for the late response as I was away this weekend but thanks for your advice!

I am now using MobaXterm as SSH client to try executing these queries. I have some troubles sending a request this way but that's a different problem.

Thanks again!